# What is the mechanism for this Horner-Wadsworth-Emmons (HWE) reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

In this reaction the HWE reaction does not give a "normal" alkene product, but instead gives (R/S)-2. Provide a reasonable mechanism for its formation?

Comment: Interesting looking problem, but we really need you to show us your thoughts on it before it gets answered otehrwise it will be closed as homework.

Answer (score 1):

First dil. aq. HCl hydrolyses the starting material to the dialdehyde.

Second the diethylphosphonoacetate anion reacts with one of the aldehyde groups to give the expected intermediate alkoxide. This is in equilibrium with the carbanion shown below. This is not normally depicted in the HWE mechanism as there is usually no pathway forward from it, however in this case there is. This carbanion can, and does, undergo a second HWE with the other aldehyde which proceeds through the usual mechanism to give the products shown in the question

[image]

Comment: Waylander: FYI, there is a skinny version of ChemDraw online. https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html

Comment: @user55119  I tried drawing it in that and failed to find a way to save it so that it would post here. Clearly I am missing a trick.

Comment: @Waylander Top menu, *Structure → Get Image*. This would result in a popup with a PNG file on top that you can save locally. Alternatively, use screen capture software.

Comment: Did you use skinny ChemDraw on the second version? I couldn't get @andselisk's first instruction to work -- what to do with all the code--but a screenshot was fine. Fortunately, I have access to the robust version of CD.

Comment: I used the link you posted. I'm more used to ISIS draw so the scheme is not as clear as I would have liked.

Comment: @user55119 Ignore the code, [grab a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ABbT.png).

Comment: @andselisk: How did you get the inset that asks "save as..."?

Comment: @user55119 Right mouse button.